# uploading file from specific location using rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I am using `rails_admin` gem. Everything is connected, and everything is working as it should.
When I go to `/admin`, I pick a `product` for example, going `Add new` and then in new window I have option like `image url` (which supposed to take name of image for example `test.png` and that's it).

What is bothering me, I would like to somehow enable that when I fill all options, and enter `image url`, also add a `browse` option near it, so when user/admin clicks on `Add Product` at the bottom of the page, image is loaded (from that PC) and added into folder in assets directory I created `assets/images/MyFolder`.

Comment: have you tried using paperclip gem with rails admin gem... it should provide the desired behaviour...

Comment: i will check it thanks. any other solutions if this one fails?

Comment: it works fine for me... so i didn't have to check other solutions :D

Comment: aha perfect. sry but i have to ask if you can provide valid tutorial for implementing this? ty anyway

Comment: for me this was the best tutorial https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start ... feel free to answer your own question and get some rep. :D

Comment: :d ty. if i have any more questions, ill ask in couple hours i guess.

Comment: @artmees dammit i think ive stumbled on some issues while implementing this, any chance of you helping? i can create live chat or smth to check this tgthr if you have time. ^^